# Discrete Mathematics (Writing statements in terms of quantified symbolic logic)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

**Problem:**

Let P(x) be the open statement “x is thick”, Q(x) be “x has a hard cover”, R(x,y) “x is more expensive than y”, S(x,y) “x is harder to read than y”, and let B be the set of all books. Write the following statements in terms of quantified symbolic logic.

I need help with the 4 questions below. Are my answers for #1 and #2 correct? For #3 and #4, I'm unsure of how to write it in quantified symbolic logic.

1. Some books are more expensive than others.

   ∃x ∈ B, ∀y ∈ B(~x), R(x, y)
2. Books with hard covers are more expensive than books without hard covers.

   ∀x ∈ B, Q(x), ∀y ∈ B, ~Q(y), R(x, y)
3. Books that are harder to read are more expensive.

   Not sure about this one
4. Any book more expensive than a thick book is also harder to read (than that thick book).

   Not sure about this one

Thank you guys, this website helps me out a lot with math! :)

Answer (score 0):

1)  B is a set, not a truth statement, so you cant have B(x)

$\exists x, y \in B, \  R(x,y)$

2) $ \forall x,y \in B, \ Q(x) \land \neg Q(y) \implies R(x,y)$

3) $ \forall x,y \in B, \ S(x,y) \implies R(x,y)$

4) $\forall x,y \in B, \ R(x,y) \land P(y)  \implies S(x,y)$

Answer (score 0):

By $B(\sim x)$ do you mean the set $B$ excepting $x$, i.e. $B\setminus\{x\}$?

1.Your first statement is not correct. You are saying that there exists some book $x$, which is more expensive than *all* other books, which is very different from what you want to say. What you want to say is that there exist some pair, with the one being more expensive than the other. I would write
$$\exists x,y \in B: \quad R(x,y)$$

2. Seems correct.
3. You're going to want to use an implication: $\Rightarrow$

*if* one book is harder to read than the other, *then* it is more expensive than the other. In contrast to question two, you are dealing with relations between books rather than sets of books. There is no set of books that are hard to read.

4. This is almost the same as the above question, except you need to specify that the book it is more expensive than has the property of being thick.